# Submit a model's form from another model's view in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a Project management app .
My system is like Project-> Feature -> Task.
A project has many features , a Feature has many tasks.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :features
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :features
end

class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

I have the project Dashboard indicated by show action-
where I have a section to add new feature, And also new task under a feature.
Now this is the code for `views/projects/show.html.erb`

```
<div class="col-md-3 colm" id="card2">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <a  href="#card2" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <h5 class="card-title">Backlog</h5>

      <div class="card-text">

      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          &plus; Add Feature
      </button>

      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <%= render "feature" %>
      </div>

      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTask" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTask">
          &plus; Add Task
      </button>
      <div class="collapse" id="collapseTask">
        <%= link_to "new task", new_project_feature_task_path(@project,1), id: "newlink", remote: true %>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the `_feature.html.erb` form is shown as

```
  <%= form_for(@project, class: "form-group row")  do |form| %>
    <%= form.fields_for :features do |builder| %>

      <%= builder.label :name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name, required: true %>

      <%= builder.label :desc %>
      <%= builder.text_field :desc %>
      <%= builder.submit class: "btn btn-primary m-2" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

But the data is not inserted in the `features` database when I checked the database

For reference the project controller class is ->'

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.features.build
  end
```

But the problem is whenever I render _feature.html.erb it gives an edit feature form instead of a new feature form, what to do to render new feature creation form inside project show page ?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot potentially wrong with your code. For instance, here:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.features.build
end
```

...probably wants to be something more like:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @feature = @project.features.build
end
```

And this:

```
<%= form_for(@project, class: "form-group row")  do |form| %>
```

...probably wants to be something more like:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @feature], class: "form-group row" do |form| %>
```

That assumes that your `features` routes are nested under your `projects` routes something like:

```
resources :projects do 
  resources :features, shallow: true do 
    resources :tasks, shallow: true 
  end
end
```

You're probably getting an edit form because you're passing an existing record into your `form_for`, again, here:

```
<%= form_for(@project, class: "form-group row")  do |form| %>
```

This also looks suspicious:

```
<%= link_to "new task", new_project_feature_task_path(@project,1), id: "newlink", remote: true %>
```

...because it seems odd to hard code the `1` in your `new_project_feature_task_path`.

Also, you're not displaying current features. And, it seems like you would want to do something like:

```
<div class="col-md-3 colm" id="card2">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <a  href="#card2" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
      <h5 class="card-title">Backlog</h5>

      <div class="card-text">

      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
          &plus; Add Feature
      </button>

      <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <%= render "feature" %>
      </div>

      <% @project.features.each do |feature| %>

        # render your feature details here

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTask" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTask">
            &plus; Add Task
        </button>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseTask">
          <%= link_to "new task", new_project_feature_task_path(@project, feature), id: "feature-#{feature.id}-new-task-link", remote: true %>
        </div>

      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And, finally, you don't show anything about how you handle your ajax call to `new_project_feature_task_path`. Presumably, that generates a form? Do you have `js` to show the form (some sort of `on ajax:success` or what have you)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed analysis, I couldnt have asked for more..Actually (the last line I forgot to remove) I want to render a form taskform which will be used to add task to respective features

Comment: its showing as  No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tasks", :feature_id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:feature_id]

Comment: What is "it" (when you say 'its showing...'). And, in what context? Where is the error being thrown?

Comment: I followed your said method for implementing task under feature with this form header->        `<%= form_for [@feature, @task], class: "form-group row"  do |builder| %>`      And rendering this form shows the error as   `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Projects#show`

Comment: Are you trying to do that inside the `@project.features.each` loop?

Comment: When inside the `@project.features.each do |feature|` loop, you want to use `feature.tasks.each do |task|`, not `@feature.tasks.each do |task|` because you're working with `feature`, not `@feature`.

Comment: I included that by wrapping with  `<% feature.tasks.each do |task| %>`  which showed the error  `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Projects#show`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197964/discussion-between-jvillian-and-achy97).